# No web.xml file in net beans 7.2.1 for mapping of context listner

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to use context listener in netBeans 7.2.1. Below is my implemented code:

```
public class contextTry implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context=sce.getServletContext();
        fetchVal obj=new fetchVal();
        Vector<RefValue> v_ref=obj.getReferenceParam();
        System.out.println("------INSIDE CONTEXT---------");
        context.setAttribute("v_Ref", v_ref);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Context destroyed");
    }
```

}

But I am getting a null pointer exception whenever I am calling the parameter.

```
public class logincontroller extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        Vector<RefValue> v=(Vector)getServletContext().getAttribute("v_ref");

        System.out.println("-----------------"+v.get(0).getStatus());
    }
```

I think I'll have to map the listener in the web.xml file but I could not find it in netBeans 7.2.1.

Please help me to figure out a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listener should be listed in `web.xml` like

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>com.yourPackage.contextTry</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Or, in case you use Servlet API 3.0 or above, you can just annotate it with `@WebListener`, you don't need `web.xml` anymore in this case.

You should also check if calling `obj.getReferenceParam()` really returns instance of `Vector`.

Couple of notes unrelated to the problem

- you should name your class according to the [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), it's a Java standard
- you shouldn't use `Vector` anymore for most cases, `List` is faster

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have set up your project to use servlet spec 3.0 or above.

Some IDEs per default do not generate a `web.xml` for those versions.

Please use [annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) to configure your context listener.